# Reverse a string then swap every nth letter

Tags: java, string

I've been stuck on this problem for two hours now.  Basically I need to reverse a string (which I've done no problem), then swap every nth letter (which is where im stuck).

Here is what I have so far:

```
    public class StringMethods {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s = "Hey there";
            int n = 2;

            System.out.println(reverseString(s));
            System.out.println(reverseStringChallenge(s, n));

        }

        private static String reverseString(String s) {
            String reversed = "";
            for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                reversed = reversed + s.charAt(i);
            }
            return reversed;
        }


        private static String reverseStringChallenge(String s, int n) {
            String reversed = "";
            String swapped = "";
            for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                reversed = reversed + s.charAt(i); // normal reverse
                }

            char [] charArray = reversed.toCharArray();  //Strings are immutable, convert string to char array

            for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
                if(i%n == 0) {  
                                //this is where im stuck
                }

            }


            return swapped;
        }

}
```

I know that strings are immutable in java so I need to convert the reversed string into a char array, and then loop through the array but not sure what to do here.

Any advice would be really appreciated.  its doing my head in.

Edit:  sorry what I mean by swap every nth letter is that say n = 2.  then every second letter gets swapped with its previous one.

Comment: What an example of an output you're expecting? Otherwise, please clarify what you mean by "swap every nth letter", because it's unclear what you want to swap this "nth letter" with.

Comment: What do you need to swap nth letter with?

Comment: Seriously... What are you trying to do??.. Give sample I/P and O/P..

Comment: I dont understand what are you trying to do. Please give example of input and output.

Comment: nooooo how can that be homework! this is pure productive code...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't clarify the swap logic, but how about something like this:

```
for(int i = n; i < charArray.length; i += n) {
    char a = charArray[i-n];
    char b = charArray[n];
    charArray[i-n] = b;
    charArray[n] = a;
}
```

Comment: for a string of length 5, with n = 2, that will swap 2 with 4 and and the swap 4 with 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic swap

```
int n = 1; 
int n1 = 2;

int temp = n;  // variable to hold n value
n = n2;    // make n = n2
n2 = temp; // make n2 = n

// now n = 2
// and n2 = 1
```

Not really sure from your question what it is you're trying to do, so I can't really give a definite answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are swapping the current char with the next char you could do something like:

```
private static String reverseStringChallenge(String s, int n) 
{

String reversed = StringUitls.reverse(s); 
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char [] charArray = reversed.toCharArray(); 

for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
 if(i%n == 0)
 {
   sb.append(charArray[i+1]).append(charArray[i]);
   i++;
 }else{
   sb.append(charArray[i]);
 }
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

I'm excuse null and out of bound checks =) good luck